# Returning image as FileContentResult .net

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm basicly trying to return a image to the client from a method on the server. It works in all browsers except IE (only tried IE 11 but guessing its the same for older).

Basicly this is what i am doing on the server:

```
public FileContentResult GetIconForFileExtention(string fileExtention, bool largeIcon = true)
{
    if (!fileExtention.StartsWith("."))
    {
        fileExtention = "." + fileExtention;
    }

    using (IconContainer icon = ShellIcons.GetIconForFile(fileExtention, true, largeIcon))
    {
        Bitmap b = icon.Icon.ToBitmap();             
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        icon.Icon.Save(ms);

        FileContentResult image = null;
        try
        {
            image = File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "icon");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
        }

        return image;
     }
}
```

This is a .net mvc application. And on the client i just load the image in a img tag like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetIconForFileExtention", "MyDocuments", new { fileExtention = "odt" })" />
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hit F12, see what the browser tells you.

Comment: I have checked the request and response in the web inspector and the image loads ok. I can see the image in the list where you can see all download times and such. I just logged off the windows machine byt can logon again in a bit and post request and response headers if that would be of any help.

Comment: What doesn't "work" then? What do you expect to happen and what do you see?

Comment: I was leaning towards a content-type or encoding problem maybe? The image content-type is set to image/png do i need to set something else?

Comment: The image is not rendered on the page. Just the 'X' symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I think your action and razor code is correct and I would try checking your `GetIconForFile` method and making sure it returns correctly the icons.

This is code that should work correctly for populating an icon as a `FileContentResult` without using the mentioned method:

```
FileContentResult image = null;

var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Server.MapPath("~") + "/favicon.ico");

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    icon.Save(ms);
    image = File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "icon");
}

return image;
```

You can try to run it and confirm the issue is not in the Action and in the Razor view, but in the ShellIcons class. Before running it make sure you have a "favicon.ico" in your root folder ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Second jobb calling. i did try your test altho not the favicon. It worked fine on chrome ie11 still fails. Did overlook the console output before I do get: "Unable to decode image at URL: <my url>" any ide?

Comment: Found the problem. icon.Icon.Save(ms); somehowe messes up the encoding. Solution change that line to b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);